# How to pass variable in mysql_query

Tags: mysql, c

I try to execute mysql query passing variable. Here is my code

```
char str[100] = "My String";

mysql_query(conn, printf("INSERT INTO table VALUES %s"), str);
```

I get that warning during compile process

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘mysql_query’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

What I miss ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that. `printf()` returns the number of characters printed. You have to create the string before calling `mysql_query()`:

```
char statement[512], *my_str = "MyString";
snprintf(statement, 512, "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('%s')", str);
mysql_query(conn, statement);
```

Also, be careful when creating those query strings. Don't use functions like `sprintf()` if you cannot be sure how long the resulting string is. Don't write over the boundaries of the memory segment.

Comment: -1 This is a bad advice, when `str` contains something like `f'); DROP TABLE table; -- ` and `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` is set, then you lose all the data in `table`.

Answer (score 4):

Extending @ckruse's answer, you should take care to use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) if your string comes from arbitrary sources.

```
int insert_data(MYSQL * mysql, char * str, int len)
{
    if (len < 0) {
        len = strlen(str);
    }

    char esc[2*len+1];
    unsigned long esclen = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql, esc, str, len);

    char statement[512];
    snprintf(statement, sizeof statement, "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('%s')", esc);
    return mysql_query(mysql, statement);
}
```

(An alternative could be [`mysql_hex_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-hex-string.html) if dealt with correctly.)

Comment: Why do you choose `int` for len? `int` is not for array sizes, use `size_t` for that, or in case it can be negative use `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Most likely, I chose it to be "safe on the right side". `mysql_real_escape_string()` expects an `unsigned long` as its input length and also returns an `unsigned long` as its output size. This answer is from over 8 years ago, but quite likely I chose this type because it is hard to predict if the `size_t` will fit into the `unsigned long`, or vice versa. But most likely, it is better to use `size_t`. I was tempted to change my answer, but I don't know if I'll leave it as it is or I will change it.

Answer (score -1):

you should put "'' in front and after the string
like this

```
mysql_query(conn, printf("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('%s')"), str);
```