# Using a variable inside a mysql_query construction as value

Tags: mysql, c, parameter-passing

I need to refill some lines of a table in mysql, and I'm using the C API. The table has 2 columns titled "VARIABLE" and "VALUE", and 4 lines with the names and values of 4 variables.

I can refill any value, for example the value of VAR1, by the code:

```
if(mysql_query(conn, "REPLACE INTO TAULA_DADES SET VARIABLE='VAR1',VALOR=3")){
finish_with_error(conn);
}
```

However, I don't know how to put the value of a C variable in the field, for example:

```
int a;
```

Comment: I don't know about this MySQL C API (perhaps there's a function to do the job) but `sprintf()` would certainly help.

Comment: Use a [Prepared Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (not tested, just an example of possible approach):

```
MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(conn);

char stmt_text[] = "REPLACE INTO TAULA_DADES SET VARIABLE=?,VALOR=?";

mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, stmt_text, strlen(stmt_text));

/* Bind the data for the 2 parameters */
MYSQL_BIND bind[2];

memset(bind, 0, sizeof(bind));

/* First parameter */
char var1[16] = "VAR1";
unsigned long var1_len = strlen(var1);

bind[0].buffer_type   = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[0].buffer        = var1;
bind[0].buffer_length = 16;
bind[0].is_null       = 0;
bind[0].length        = &var1_len;

/* Second parameter */
int a = 123;

bind[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
bind[1].buffer      = (char *)&a;
bind[1].is_null     = 0;
bind[1].length      = 0;

mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, bind);
mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);
mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
```

In the real program you should check the return value of each statement adding the code for error management.

You can also pass variables via `sprintf` (e.g. take a look at [How to pass variable in mysql_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531760/how-to-pass-variable-in-mysql-query-in-c)) but it presents a higher security risk (at least consider the [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) function for user-supplied values).

Further details:

- [mysql_stmt_execute()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html)
- [C API Prepared Statement Data Structures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-statement-data-structures.html)